# SAS- Put function used to convert bigint to char - generating incorrect ouptut

Tags: sas, bigint

I need to access bigint data for processing. So i am trying to convert it into character and process it. However i noticed that some bigint numbers were not appearing in the output table. I tried doing a sample program listed below, that is replicating the issue.

```
data m;
x=put (57259186099807233,20.);
run;

proc print data =m;
quit;
```

Why does this give me output “57259186099807232”?

Thanks in advance.
NV

Comment: Once you've read it in as numeric it won't be read in correctly. You need to change your process to read it in as character in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

See [http://support.sas.com/documentation/...](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm)

The largest integer value that can be 'safely' stored in SAS (on windows systems) is 9,007,199,254,740,992 which is smaller than the value in your example.

With bigger values, you will inevitably lose precision; fact which your example illustrates quite well.